# Inline if condition with nil in swift

Tags: swift, null, inline

I am trying to use inline if condition as follows:

```
topDisplay.text = topDisplay.text!.rangeOfString(".") ? "Sth for true" : "Sth for false"
```

The idea here is if there is "." in the topDisplay.text! then do something, if not, do something else. The method, rangeOfString, returns nil if no "." is found. So I am wondering is it possible to check nil within inline condition expression.

((btw, you might find out that I am trying to add "." button for calculator assignment in Stanford's online course, and to use only one line to implement this function as the hint describes))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I am wondering is it possible to check nil within inline condition expression.

Sure. `rangeOfString(".") != nil` is a *boolean* expression which can
be used as the condition in the conditional expression:

```
topDisplay.text = topDisplay.text!.rangeOfString(".") != nil ? "Sth for true" : "Sth for false"
```

Comment: Just to note that `rangeOfString` doesn't return an optional. He would have to compare with `NSNotFound` instead.

Comment: @Alladinian: The rangeOfString() method of NSString returns an NSRange. The rangeOfString() method of a Swift `String` returns an optional `Range<String.Index>`. – The `text` property of `UILabel` or `UITextField` is a Swift String.

Comment: Hmm you're right... That is really confusing though since the docs contain this signature `func rangeOfString(_ aString: String) -> NSRange` and `rangeOfString()` is only available _after_ you import `Foundation`! Thanks for this :)

Comment: Thanks @Alladinian and Martin R. One more quit question, is it as well possible that calling a function within this kind of expression? eg: "Sth for true" --> Some function for true.

Comment: @Yao: Yes, it is possible.