# Calling function within inline condition expression in Swift

Tags: function, swift, null, inline

I am trying to use inline if condition as follows:

```
topDisplay.text!.rangeOfString(".") != nil ? call function A : call function B
```

The idea here is if there is `"."` in the `topDisplay.text!` then call function A, otherwise, call function B. The method, `rangeOfString`, returns nil if no "." is found. So I am wondering is it possible to check nil within inline condition expression and making function call at the same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inline if condition with nil in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392878/inline-if-condition-with-nil-in-swift)

Comment: topDisplay.text!.rangeOfString(".") ? functionA() : functionB()
Above expression just wouldn't compile. Anything should be changed?

Comment: The first thing would be to use `rangeOfString(".") != nil ? ...` as suggested in the answer to your previous question ...

Comment: sorry for the confusion Martin, my previous comment should be

topDisplay.text!.rangeOfString(".") != nil ? functionA() : functionB()

and this post is corrected too.

Comment: @Yao You may have a typo somewhere, look at [this screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s236/sh/8b8865b1-22c3-48fe-9a89-c40c95abf782/60269ecaf23c9753/res/3b01d602-ad2a-4147-8801-ce800f734ea2/skitch.png).

Comment: `topDisplay.text.flatMap { find($0, ".").map { _ in functionA() } } ?? functionB()` (do not do this, only for my amusement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, assuming you put the calls to actual functions in there, i.e.:

```
func functionA() -> String { return "A" }
func functionB() -> String { return "B" }

topDisplay.text?.rangeOfString(".") != nil ? functionA() : functionB()
```

If you’re getting an error message, the most likely reason is `functionA` and `functionB` return different types:

```
func functionA() -> String { return "A" }
func functionB() -> Int { return 1 }

// error: could not find an overload for '!=' that accepts the supplied arguments
topDisplay.text?.rangeOfString(".") != nil ? functionA() : functionB()
```

In classic Swift error message style, this gives you an error about the valid `!=` comparison not about the problem with `A` and `B` returning incompatible types.

However, given you aren’t showing in your code the assignment of the result, I suspect you are actually wanting to run these functions for their side-effects not for the value they return.  If this is the case **do not do this**.  The `?:` operator is there for evaluating two possibilities as an expression.  If you want side effects, use an `if`:

```
if topDisplay.text?.rangeOfString(".") != nil {
    sideEffectfulFunctionA()
}
else {
    sideEffectfulFunctionB()
}
```

Comment: I actually want functionA and functionB to do something other than just return a string. In fact, as my code shows, I am not assigning any return value to any string. All I want to do is trying to express the if/else statement in single one line. It looks like it's not possible here, thanks !